# SSRS2016 Convert seconds to hh:mm:ss format

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2016

I have a table with a column, `Duration` that has value in seconds.

In `Visual Studio / SSRS 2016` I want to display it in `HH:MM:SS` format.

I have tried to use the following expressions

`=Format(DateAdd("s", Fields!Duration.Value, "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss")`

But it didn't seem to work correctly, for example, `1800s` will be displayed as `01:38:00`

Can anybody see the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: I've just created a simple report and your expression works as I would expect. i.e. 1800 was returned as 00:30:00 . What datatype is the duration column in your dataset?

Comment: @AlanSchofield Hi thx for your reply, the datatype is INTEGER

Comment: Are you sure that the value is 1800 ? It should work as you have it.Add another textbox with the expression `=Fields!Duration.Value` and make sure it returns what you expect. I expect it will not. If the scope of the textbox is an aggregation such as `=SUM(Fields!Duration.Value)` then you will need to do the same within you conversion expression.

Comment: @AlanSchofield it has worked now, I should have applied this expression on the ''Value'' property, but instead I tried to change the number format.

Comment: Thanks for your time! But I still have a problem here, the textbox display the number as I wished in hh:mm:ss format, but the chart which was generated from this table still display 1800s, what should I do now?

Comment: You need to start a new question specifically about this problem. It's best to show a sample of your data, what you get now and what you expect it to look like based on your sample data. If you do this people will help you faster.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a number of seconds to time format use the TimeSerial function:

```
=Format(TimeSerial(0,0,Fields!Duration.Value),"HH:mm:ss")
```

The problem with your way might be that it is not implicitly converting from the text string to time format as you expect, so the following may also work:

```
=Format(DateAdd("s", Fields!Duration.Value, TimeValue("00:00:00")), "HH:mm:ss")
```

Comment: I have tried this too, but it has also returned 01:38:00

Comment: Try forcing the duration to integer with CINT

Comment: If that still doesn't work, add the duration in the same scope and check it is returning the value you believe it is.

Comment: it is working now, I should have applied this expression on the ''Value'' property, but instead I tried to change the number format. sorry for my stupid question and thx for your help!